# Sql - Count table query error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I want to display the owner and the number of times they took the car, bus or train to work.
so the table should look like this;

```
Owner | Car | Bus | Train
-------------------------
Joe   | 1   | 2   | 4
```

This is my query;

```
Select owner, vehicle
From MyTable
    INNER JOIN(select  
  count(case when vehicle = 'Car' then 1 else 0 end) AS [Car],
  count(case when vehicle = 'Bus' then 1 else 0 end) AS [Bus],
  count(case when vehicle = 'Train' then 1 else 0 end) AS [Train]
from dbo.MyTable
where
     YEAR([CreatedOn]) = 2015
group by 
    vehicle)
```

Im getting an incorrect syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `sum()` rather than `count()`.  Second, you don't need a subquery.  Third, you need to group by `owner`, not `vehicle`:

```
Select owner,
       sum(case when vehicle = 'Car' then 1 else 0 end) AS [Car],
       sum(case when vehicle = 'Bus' then 1 else 0 end) AS [Bus],
       sum(case when vehicle = 'Train' then 1 else 0 end) AS [Train]
From MyTable
where YEAR([CreatedOn]) = 2015
group by owner;
```

You can use `count()`, but it counts non-NULL values, so it is misleading.  In your case, for instance, the conditional logic is ignored.

EDIT:

To get the rest, use the same idea, just change the condition:

```
       sum(case when vehicle not in ('Car', 'Bus', 'Train') then 1 else 0 end) AS Others
```

Comment: thanks, how could I count the rest that is not car,bus,train?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select owner
    ,count(case when vehicle = 'Car' then 1 end) as [Car]
    ,count(case when vehicle = 'Bus' then 1 end) as [Bus]
    ,count(case when vehicle = 'Train' then 1 end) as [Train]
from dbo.MyTable
where year([CreatedOn]) = 2015
group by owner
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `ELSE 0` becuase it will be counted. Use `ELSE NULL` or leave default.

```
Select owner,
     count(case when vehicle = 'Car' then 1 end) AS [Car],
     count(case when vehicle = 'Bus' then 1 end) AS [Bus],
     count(case when vehicle = 'Train' then 1 end) AS [Train],
     count(case when vehicle NOT IN ('Car', 'Bus', 'Train') 
                OR vehicle IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS [Others]
from dbo.MyTable
where YEAR([CreatedOn]) = 2015
group by owner;
```

Comment: @AndroidAL `thanks, how could I count the rest that is not car,bus,train` See updated